# Remove a sublist from a list in Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I have a function which adds two polynomials together, however if the sum of two polynomials comes to 0 then that is still being returned in the answer. I need to be able to remove 0 coefficients and their terms from my list.

My polynomials are represented such that 5x^2 is ((5((2 x))))

For example if a polynomial was 2x^2+3y+0x^2 it would look like.

```
((5 ((2 x)))
 (3 ((1 y)))
 (0 ((2 x))))
```

I have some code which identifies if the first list in the list has a 0 coefficient but I am struggling to get it to recurse through the list and remove if the coefficient is 0.

Here is my code:

```
(defun my-remove(a)
  (if(null a)
     a
     (if(equal (car(car a)) 0)
        t
        nil)))
```

At the moment it just returns true if the coefficient of the first list is 0 and false if it isn't.

Comment: Why not use the Common Lisp `remove` function?

Comment: `(if condition t nil)` is just `condition`.

Comment: I'm struggling with the syntax. I've looked at this example `(remove '(1 2) '((1 2) (1 3)) :test #'equal)` but I'm not sure what to put in the place of equal. I tried putting a 0 but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you try to substitute a function argument for a number argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CL-USER 52 > (remove 0 '((5 ((2 x)))
                         (3 ((1 y)))
                         (0 ((2 x))))
                     :key #'first)
((5 ((2 X))) (3 ((1 Y))))
```

Comment: Thanks that is great! I've never come across 'first' before but I've read upon it, am I right it saying that it is the same as car? I've tried it with car and it works exactly the same, I just want to be certain.

Comment: Yes, `first` is an alias for `car` _functionally_, there is also `rest` for `cdr`.  I usually use `first`/`rest` for things that are conceptually lists, but `car` and `cdr` for other cons cells.

Comment: @rainer-joswig How am I able to incorporate this into a function? I feel like it should be obvious but I am struggling with the syntax. At the moment I have.`(defun my-remove(a)
  (remove 0 a :key #'first))`but it doesn't work as the value A is not of the expected type list.

Comment: @JaAnTr: Then it seems that you do not pass a list to your function.